# Using Cramer's V to find which variable has the strongest correlation

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, cramers-v

Apologies in advance if this has been asked before; I'm a stats amateur and wasn't having much luck with my searches. I'm currently analyzing product data, and I'm trying to find which variables (all nominal categorical) are most strongly associated with conversion from trial product to sold product. To elaborate a bit more: in the trial product, there are certain actions that the user can complete, and I want to see which of these completed actions has the strongest correlation with the product selling.

I already used a Chi-square Test of Association to confirm that there is indeed a correlation between each action being completed and the product selling, but I now want to be able to compare each action and see which one has the strongest correlation, so that I can form hypotheses about which may be most beneficial to encourage the user to complete. Would finding the Cramer's V for each action and then comparing these values be a valid way to answer this question? In other words, if one variable has a higher Cramer's V value than another variable in the same dataset, then is it correct to conclude that this variable has a stronger correlation with the outcome than the other?

Answer (score 0):

By analyzing your contingency tables separately, the risk is to find spurious relationships ([correlation does not imply causation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation)), in particular if the actions you mention are related between them (e.g. are users who take action A also likely to take action B?).

You might end up requiring users to take some actions when there is no need to. Other methods like [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) could be more adequate to analyze your data. (I don't know what other users think about it, but you could ask another question about what kind of methods would be appropriate in your scenario; it will require you to give more details about your data and use case.)

But let's imagine for a second that [confounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confounding) is not a problem for analyzing the contingency tables you have, and let's consider Cramér's V.

You want to find actions that are beneficial, which I interpret as you wanting to identify actions that are likely to increase sales if you incite users to complete them.

A pitfall here is that Cramér's V won't tell you anything about the directionality of the effect. In your case, a given Cramér's V can be indistinctly associated with larger or smaller sales compared to other tables. Consider the three following contingency tables, describing the behavior of potential customers (you don't mention what your data look like, so I'm guessing here):

| Table 1 | don't buy | buy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| take action A | 1900 | 100 |
| don't take action A | 1500 | 500 |

| Table 2 | don't buy | buy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| take action B | 100 | 1900 |
| don't take action B | 500 | 1500 |

| Table 3 | don't buy | buy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| take action C | 1000 | 1000 |
| don't take action C | 900 | 1100 |

The two first tables mirror each other, so they have the exact same Cramér's V (0.28), however their number of sales is completely different.

In addition, if you compare the first table to the third one, you see that sales in table 3 are higher both in absolute values and row-wise proportions, despite having a smaller Cramér's V (0.05).

So Cramér's V won't tell you if taking an action is related to an increase or a decrease in sales, if you compare it to other contingency tables. In the case of 2x2 tables, looking at the [odds ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds_ratio) would certainly be more informative.

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough response! That's a good point about confounding variables; I'll look into other methods that can better deal with this. 

One follow-up question: the impression I'm getting is that the main issue with Cramer's V is the lack of directionality; if I have few enough variables to observe the contingency tables directly and tell that the directionality is the same for all of the variables' effects, would comparing Cramer's V values be valid in this case? Or would you still advise against it?

Comment: @AshM In your place, with 2x2 tables, I'd use the odds ratio (or possibly the risk ratio). Even if the directionality is the same, Cramér's $V$ is affected by the distribution of the *two* variables; see an example here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/632240/164936 - NB: phi ($\phi$) is the same thing as $V$ for 2x2 tables. // I think it's too easy to incorrectly interpret $V$ for the kind of question you have. Using another effect size like the odds ratio or the risk ratio would be perfectly valid and directly informative, so why not simply use that?

Comment: @AshM By the way, if you found my answer useful, you can accept it, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235