# Can Cramér's V or contingency coefficient be used if chi-squared assumptions are not met?

Tags: chi-squared-test, assumptions, contingency-tables, cramers-v

I am testing for the independence of a specific set of variables with respect to a common event. Despite having a fairly decent sample size (n=236), the event I am testing for is relatively rare (2% of the sample). Consequently, when constructing my contingency tables, many cells for various variables have an expected count of less than 5.

As far as I recall, whenever this count is greater than 20%, there's a violation of chi-squared assumptions, and therefore, another test should be used instead. I have been taught that Fisher's exact test is well-suited for such instances.

I would like to conduct some measures of strength of association for those variables that exhibit a significant association with the event. However, I am unsure whether coefficients of effect size such as the contingency coefficient or Cramér's V, which rely on the value of chi-square, can be used when chi-square assumptions aren't met.

Although I have already computed the relative risk (as I am conducting a cohort study), I am concerned that comparing variable strength of association based solely on their relative risks could become convoluted. Thus, I believe Cramér's V or a similar measure might be better suited for the task.

I would highly appreciate it if you could confirm whether this measurement can be used and, if not, suggest alternative approaches.

Comment: Hello Daniel and welcome on CrossValidated. You mention relative risk: are the dimensions of all your contingency tables 2x2? If so, you might be interested in this discussion: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/632234/164936 (phi equals Cramér's V for 2x2 tables). Another discussion that could interest you: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93212/what-to-do-when-i-have-expected-count-5-warning-for-a-chi-squared-test

Comment: contingency coefficient or Cramer's V are not  tests on their own - they are coefficients of effect size, standardized expressions of the chi-square statistic.

Comment: Agreed with ttnphns's comment, I edited Daniel's question to correct the issue. @Daniel, you should make sure you understand the difference between a test and a measure of effect size (I guess you do, but that you used the word "test" too loosely). If you don't see the difference, then you should mention it, so possible answers can address it and give you an explanation. In addition, you should mention what are the dimensions of your tables, and how observations have been sampled. Finally, you should probably give more details as to why you think using relative risk could become convoluted.